# Why email of Jenkins user is registered again if I didn't changed

Tags: jenkins

When I go Manage Jenkins -> user management. Then I select the jenkins user and press 'Configure'
His email textbox is registered (eg. Bob@example.com). I changed the value of email textbox to empty and I pressed Save and Apply. After several days, I checked the jenkins user again and I saw that email text is registered as Bob@example.com.
I can figure out that another jenkins user registered the email again. The question is can be it the only reason?

Comment: Which authentication type are you using for Jenkins?

Comment: I log in through its Jenkins' webpage. I don't know if it answers the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Jenkins doesn't allow an empty email for a user if you set the default email domain in the global configuration settings. In that case it will always update the empty user mail to `<username>@<default_domain>`.
If you remove the default domain configuration, then you should be able to set the user's email address to an empty value, but you loose the benefits of having a default domain.

This behavior is more a feature then bug as the goal of the default email domain setting is to automatically compute user's email based on the username - so Jenkins tries to infer the email address, and when the address is not given it uses the default suffix combined with the user name to create it, as some would expect.

Therefore you will have to find a different way to disable mails for a particular user.
There is an open improvement request for that ability at [JENKINS-16765](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-16765).